# Import Word 2007 bibliography into JabRef?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I have a bibliography list in Word 2007, but want to import them into JabRef (bibTex). I have searched around, the bibliography in Word is stored in an XML file, but JabRef does not import via such format? I wonder if there is an efficient way to do this so I don't need to add the entries one by one. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of anything that will work without bother.  For Word 2007, Reference Manager will [export Word's bibliography](http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/releasing-reference-manager-beta-for-word-2007/) to Bibtex.  The next release is intended to handle Word 2010 bibliographies.  I have the impression that you can import the 2010 format sources.xml files into Word 2007, with Word 2007 dropping what it doesn't understand, but I can't recall where I got the idea.

One of the authors of the JabRef Word References exporters wrote a bit about converting between the two formats: see his [Details of Microsoft Office 2007 Bibliographic Format Compared to BibTex](http://mahbub.wordpress.com/2007/03/24/details-of-microsoft-office-2007-bibliographic-format-compared-to-bibtex/).  It looks hard to do cleanly.